# Implement universal image loader on custom listvew Android

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

How do I implement this? I've been looking everywhere and I'm lost. If someone could enlighten me that would be great. This is my current custom `adapter`:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final String[] imageUrls;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, String[] imageUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    //imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, null);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;
  };
}
```

Note that the above code has some errors. First, at the `activity.getApplicationContext()`: I don't know why. For the second one, the imageLoader says it cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in the below link https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final String[] imageUrls;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, String[] imageUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);

    this.context = context;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, null);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

don't forget initialization ImageLoader in application class.

Comment: the activity.getApplicartionContext() still giving me error... and how do make initialization? this is my first time using universal image loader so i'm at loss here.

Answer (score 0):

okay I resolved my problem, maybe I should share it here for people in the future :)

first I have to initialize the `ImageLoader` in main activity(not in the customlistadapter) like this:

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getBaseContext()));
```

next I call the ImageLoader from the customlistadapter:

`MainActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position],imageView);`

and the declaration of the ImageLoader :

`public static ImageLoader imageLoader;`

I don't know if it would cause any problem if declared public and static, but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try implementing the below code in your adapter 

         ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        DisplayImageOptions option = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000)).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();


        imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl,imageview,option);
```